# PHP PDO - Multiple Statements - if 1 fails, don't execute the other

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo, statements

So I've got this `PHP Service` which is connect to my `Android` app and it executes 2 queries at once. I've read how to detect if one fails and I know that one of mine fails because EventSlots is already 0 and is an `INT unsigned`.

However, the other statement is successful and gets executed. Obviously, I want to only execute both, and if 1 fails, `don't execute anything at all` but return an error for my App.

How would I detect if one of the statements failed and `STOP the other` from executing? I probably can avoid using multiple statements and do 1, check if it was OK and only then execute the other. Can I achieve that with multiple statements though?

**Query**:

```
"INSERT INTO GuestList(EventID, AccountID) VALUES (7, (SELECT AccountID FROM Accounts WHERE Username = 'test'));
 UPDATE Events SET EventSlots = EventSlots-1 WHERE EventID = 7 ;"
```

Comment: Use a transaction http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: If you know _why_ the first statement fails (as you wrote), then why do you have to execute anything at all? You know that _prior_ to executing it, since you have all information involved.

Comment: Thanks @JimL I didn't even know about those. Seem very useful, I will try those now. And `arkascha`, I know this because I'm testing that specific Use Case. I set the EventSlots to 0 in order to implement a handler in my app for when a user tries to attend an event which already has 0 slots available (i know that but he wouldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PDO transactions http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php . A transaction represents a bunch of queries that has to be executed in a atomic way. If something fails during the transaction it will automatically performs a rollback to the initial state.